# How to retrieve list items title using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-jsom

I'm trying to retrieve list items Title  to insert it into a div section in my SharePoint home page, I've found this code which retrieve item URL.

it works just fine.

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Artdesk alertes");

var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
caml.set_viewXml("<View />");

var listItemCollection = list.getItems(caml);

clientContext.load(list, "DefaultDisplayFormUrl");
clientContext.load(listItemCollection);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {

    for(var i in listItemCollection.get_data()) {

        console.log( "DispFormRelativeUrl: " + list.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl() + "?ID=" +listItemCollection.get_data()[i].get_id() );
    }

}, function(sender, args) {
    window.console && console.log(args.get_message());  
});
```

How do I get the list item Title using the JavaScript object model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clientContext.load(list, "DefaultDisplayFormUrl");
```

You are requesting "DefaultDisplayFormUrl" property here.
You can specify Title property or just remove requesting specific properties to get every one of them (not recommended - you must request only those you need to reduce load).
So it will be `clientContext.load(list, "Title")` or `clientContext.load(list);`

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {    
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();       
        console.log("List Title", oListItem.get_item('Title'));
    }
}, <...>);
```

Note that you can get any property via `get_item` method (but you must request to load that property or it will throw an exception).

Here is the working code:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Artdesk alertes");

var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
caml.set_viewXml(""); // empty query also works

var listItemCollection = list.getItems(caml);

clientContext.load(listItemCollection); // i requested every property

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var listItemEnumerator = listItemCollection.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        console.log(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
    }

}, function(sender, args) {
    window.console && console.log(args.get_message());  
});
```

Comment: thanks for the explination it work just fine , i have only one last question ,
how can i do to retrieve only the 2 last  items of my list ?

Comment: You should use caml query for that. Here is query to retrieve last items
`<View>
 <Query>
  <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>
 </Query>
 <RowLimit>2</RowLimit>
</View>`

OrderBy node - you tell sharepoint to order items by id field in Descending order (there is not Descending attribute so use Ascending='FALSE').
RowLimit node - take only 2 items.
It goes here `caml.set_viewXml(<caml query string>);`
Note that in lists with 4999+ items you will get threshold error.

Comment: thanks, in my html page i have a div tag : <div id="aletres"></div>
how can i put the result of my js fonction in the div ?
thanks for the help

Comment: document.getElementById('aletres').innerText = <variable with results>;

Comment: when i put the result in document.getElementById('aletres').innerText = result;
i get only one item, however in the console log i get the 2 last ones??

Comment: You have to store all values while iterating through them.

Answer (score 0):

Check **get_item('Title')** on this code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx):

```
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + 
        '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
    );
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    ); 
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: hi thank you i've try it and it does'nt   work in for me

Comment: yes when i put it in the console  , i have no result only undefined

Comment: Are you using ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded ?